# How to send email with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send emails while creating a user.
I followed the instruction on the Internet but when I run `rails s` and create a user, no email sent to my mailbox. Anybody knows why? 
I can see the message in my cmd as below, but no email received in my mailbox app:

```
Delivered mail 5e7a798d352b0_2ef0530c80914@xdh-virtual-machine.mail (2.7ms)
Date: Tue, 24 Mar 2020 17:20:13 -0400
From: daihaoxue1996@gmail.com
To: daihaoxue@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <5e7a798d352b0_2ef0530c80914@xdh-virtual-machine.mail>
Subject: Sample Email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5e7a798d2fa66_2ef0530c808c5";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Below is my code:
ponies_controller:

```
  def create
    @pony = Pony.new(pony_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pony.save
        ExampleMailer.sample_email(@pony).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @pony, notice: 'Pony was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pony }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @pony.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

mailers/example_mailer.rb

```
class ExampleMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "daihaoxue1996@gmail.com"

  def sample_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Sample Email')
  end

end
```

production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => "daihaoxue1996@gmail.com",
 :password             => "AAAAAAAAA",
 :authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Does @pony have email attribute? Also you probably want to `deliver_now` instead of `deliver`.

Comment: Yes @pony has. I tried deliver_now but it does not work either. Actually I can see the message in my cmd but I cannot see it in my real mailbox.

Comment: So that means there is something wrong with your configurations. Do you want to check whether `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` is true in development.rb. That's where you are sending it from right?

Comment: Have you turned on lesser secure apps option in gmail? https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I do not have this line: ```config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries``` and I added it and set it as true, but still does not work.

Comment: And yes, I haved turned on the option.

Comment: I can see the message like this:```Delivered mail 5e7a798d352b0_2ef0530c80914@xdh-virtual-machine.mail (2.7ms)
Date: Tue, 24 Mar 2020 17:20:13 -0400
From: daihaoxue1996@gmail.com
To: daihaoxue@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <5e7a798d352b0_2ef0530c80914@xdh-virtual-machine.mail>
Subject: Sample Email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5e7a798d2fa66_2ef0530c808c5";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit```

Comment: I didn't think it sent mails in a development environment. You can use something like LetterOpener to check email delivery/formatting/etc. https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener